# Domain not created in Parallel Plesk Panel

Tags: dns, plesk, windows-hosting

I am using Parallels Plesk Panel 9.5.4. When creating one domain "www.elixir.edu.np" following error occurs:

The operation you were performing failed. You can retry the operation with or without changing its parameters. You may also want to report this problem to our support so that we could help you as soon as possible.

```
Additional Details
********************

Failed domain creation: Unable to update domain data: Failed mail post-configuration: Can't create mail domain servie: mailManager->addDomain() failed: mailmng failed: MEAOPO.PostOffice.AddPostOffice failed for name elixir.edu.np [elixir.edu.np]
---------------------- Debug Info -------------------------------
0: DomainPropertiesUIPointer.php:284
DomainPropertiesUIPointer->accessItem_create(string 'POST')
1: DomainPropertiesUIPointer.php:62
DomainPropertiesUIPointer->accessItem(string 'POST', NULL null)
2: UIPointer.php:601
UIPointer->access(string 'POST')
```

Other domain are created without any errors. I have tried similar domain name like: "elixir1.edu.np" | "eelixir.edu.np", these are created successfully except above mentioned one. Please any help??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a programming question, should be on serverfault

Comment: You can find the cause and resolution here: http://kb.parallels.com/en/1795

Answer (score 1):

> MEAOPO.PostOffice.AddPostOffice failed for name elixir.edu.np

This means that domain can't be created in MailEnable.
Check MailEnable Administrator panel, probably such domain already exists in MailEnable, but absent in Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

before creating domain check whether the domain already exist on plesk, iis & dns records in windows.

please remove the records before creating.